# How to list all roles associated with an AWS SSO account

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am new to AWS.

Having a list of AWS SSO account aliases and account IDs, I need to iterate through those and check whether they have a specific role assigned to them.

What is the best way to do it? Note that, every account has a specific role associated to it, which I can assume in order to access everything in that account.

For example, given the account ID 999999999999, I guess I could do something like the following:

aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::999999999999:role/CommonMemberAccess" --role-session-name "MY-SESSION"

The above will print a JSON object with AccessKeyId, SecretAccessKey and SessionToken.

I could then export the above as env variables, for example,

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AccessKeyId
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=SecretAccessKey
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=SessionToken
```

And finally, list the roles within the specific account as follows

```
aws iam list-roles
```

Eventually, I will need to do the above by connecting to the AWS API using Go (I am also new to Go). But as a starting point, I would like to know what I can do using the command line aws client.

Is the above a reasonable approach? How would you do this better?

Comment: yes, reasonable approach.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this cli command.

```
aws iam list-roles --path-prefix /aws-reserved/sso.
```

Another way that you can filter IAM roles associated with SSO is by checking their ‘AssumeRolePolicyDocument’.
The ‘Principal’ attribute has to be the ARN of a federated identity provider which has its metadata document issued by AWS SSO
(you can check its SAML metadata XML document with the following cli command),

```
aws iam get-saml-provider --saml-provider-arn “arn:of:federated:saml-provider:from:AssumeRolePolicy”
```